# Query summarized data including code with subgroup

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

I have a table with CODE and amounts. The CODE has 1 Level (Group and Subgroup).

Example:

```
CODE     Amount
R332     $45.22
R332.4   $12.11
R332.6   $9.19
R332.1   $5.01
R332.8   $4.56
M109.1   $12.22
M109     $34.0
M109.2   $65.55
M109.9   $10.3
.....
```

I need to get the SUM of all R332, including the subgroup.

I have:

SELECT SUM(amount) as total 
FROM sample_data
GROUP BY code

> Do I have to GROUP BY SUBSTRING(?) or there is other way to do it?

Thanks

Comment: Yes, group by substring is the most straight-forward approach.

Answer (score 1):

If I'm understanding your question correctly, then something like this should work just using `LIKE`:

```
SELECT SUM(amount) as total 
FROM sample_data
WHERE Code Like 'R322%'
```